# How to create custom extension method for a custom class?

Tags: c#, combobox, extension-methods

i found this class and I use it to generate items for my Combo Boxes (as a datasource):

```
 public class ComboBoxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

The problem is whenever I need the access the selected value of a `ComboBox`, it always returns the `Text`, Although the `value` and the `Text` are both visible when I parse my app, I can't access the `Value`. see the picture:

[image: ToString()]
**and this pic:**
[image: Value not accessible]

I guess I need a `ToInt()` function to return the Value of my class as an int. How can I achieve it ?

Comment: You don't need an extension method for this problem at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast SelectedItem to ComboBoxItem, then access it's Value property :

```
var i = ((ComboBoxItem)sTD_PROVINCEComboBox.SelectedItem).Value;
```

With that `i` will contain the `Value`, so in the `foreach` you can simply do as follow :

```
foreach(var item in UE2.Cities.Where(x => x.CITY_PROVINCE_ID == i)
```

**UPDATE :**

Just notice that `Value` property of `ComboBoxItem` is of type object (I was assuming it is int). If this is the case, the above foreach part won't compile (comparing int with object is not allowed). Assuming `CITY_PROVINCE_ID` is of type int, and `i` storing boxed int you'll need to unbox `i` back to int :

```
foreach(var item in UE2.Cities.Where(x => x.CITY_PROVINCE_ID == (int)i)
```

Comment: This will still not work as you're testing reference equality between 2 objects (boxed integers). That is, if CITY_PROVINCE_ID is of type object. I suspect it's of type int though, in which case this doesn't even compile.

Comment: @jeroenh you're right, I didn't notice `Value` property is an object instead of int. Going to fix my answer, thx for correction.

Answer (score 2):

To access the `Value` property, you need to cast the SelectedItem to the right type:

```
object i = ((ComboBoxItem)sTD_PROVINCEComboBox.SelectedItem).Value;
```

Note that i is of type object. I suppose that the `CITY_PROVINCE_ID` is of type `int`. You can not test for reference equality of an object and an int, so a statement like this does not even compile:

```
foreach(var item in UE2.Cities.Where(x => x.CITY_PROVINCE_ID == i)
```

The error message will be something along the lines of "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'".

What you can do instead is cast the object back to an int:

```
object o = ((ComboBoxItem)sTD_PROVINCEComboBox.SelectedItem).Value;
int i = (int)o;
```

This will obviously only work if you're only ever storing `int`s as values. If `Value` might contain something else (say, a string), you need to test against that as well;

Comment: Thanks jeorenh.
I didn't get that error and I think your solution works too.